# ExpressJS re-query database after adding record to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to expressJS and i'm wondering what is the best way to requery the database (mongo in my case) to get all the records after one is added.

```
exports.get = function (db) {
    return function (req, res) {

        var collection = db.get('notes');

        collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
            res.send(docs);
        });
    };
};

exports.create = function (db) {
    return function (req, res) {

        var title = req.body.title;
        var note = req.body.note;
        var collection = db.get('notes');

        // Insert/update the note
        collection.insert(
            {
              "title": title,
              "note": note
            },

            function (err, doc) {
                // If it failed, return error
                if (err) {
                    res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database. Error: "+err);
                } else {
                    //res.redirect('/');
                  //res.json(db.get('notes'));
                  // WHAT IS THE BEST THING TO DO HERE TO GET ALL THE RECORDS INCLUDING THE ONE I'VE JUST ADDED?
                  exports.get(db);

                }
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace

```
exports.get(db);
```

for

```
collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
    res.send(docs);
});
```

The reason is that you are invoking this in the callback, AFTER the record has been inserted

Comment: This works, but just out of curiousity, why can't I call `exports.get(db);` just like I had in the callback? It obviously didn't work and that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `exports.get` function return a `function`, a kind of middleware I see.
Repplace

```
exports.get(db);
```

by

```
exports.get(db)();
```

Comment: This causes an exception: `Cannot call method 'send' of undefined` on this line in the `exports.get` method: `res.send(docs);`